# Linux group and permission - why I can't access a folder I already have permission to?

Tags: linux, permissions, user

I followed a [link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) to install GitLab on my Linux server today, in the Gitolite section, there are two lines to set permission and ownership of a folder:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwXs,o-rwx /home/git/repositories/
sudo chown -R git:git /home/git/repositories/
```

And before these lines, it created a user and added it to a specific group:

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' gitlab
sudo usermod -a -G git gitlab
```

I checked the user and permissions after these steps:

```
gitlab@vm-leader:/home/git$ id
uid=1001(gitlab) gid=1001(gitlab) groups=1001(gitlab),105(git)
gitlab@vm-leader:/home/git$ ls -al
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 8 git  git  4096 Jan  4 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jan  4 11:50 ..
-rw------- 1 git  git    87 Jan  4 17:02 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x 2 git  git  4096 Jan  4 14:04 bin
drwx------ 2 git  git  4096 Jan  4 14:04 .cache
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  398 Jan  4 14:04 gitlab.pub
drwxr-xr-x 5 git  git  4096 Jan  4 14:01 gitolite
drwxr-x--- 6 git  git  4096 Jan  4 14:04 .gitolite
-rw-r--r-- 1 git  git  5064 Jan  4 14:04 .gitolite.rc
-rw-r--r-- 1 git  git    37 Jan  4 14:04 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 git  git    12 Jan  5 19:43 projects.list
drwsrws--- 6 git  git  4096 Jan  5 17:29 repositories
drwx------ 2 git  git  4096 Jan  5 19:43 .ssh
gitlab@vm-leader:/home/git$
```

Based on these outputs, I believe the folder 'repositories' is allowed for the same group of users to access, in this case, the group 'git' has permission to access this folder. Also, the user 'gitlab' belongs to the group 'git'. So the 'gitlab' user should be able to access that folder.
However, I got this:

```
gitlab@vm-leader:/home/git$ cd repositories/
bash: cd: repositories/: Permission denied
gitlab@vm-leader:/home/git$
```

Why did this happen and how to fix it?

Additional information:

```
bear@vm-leader:/home/git$ ls -ld /home/git
drwxr-xr-x 8 git git 4096 Jan  4 16:55 /home/git
```

Comment: @izomorphius: The question will almost certainly get migrated there, and the OP doesn't need to do anything for that to happen.

Comment: Have you logged out gitlab and then logged in again, so the new group gets active?

Comment: @ott I'm sure I logged gitlab out and in......

Comment: Can you show the output of `id` as gitlab?

Comment: I have learned the hard way that you have to have execute (x) permissions on a folder to `cd` into it.

Comment: `g+s` includes the `x`.

Comment: @ott-- I already attached it :-) Just above 'ls' output.

Comment: I created a directory and set the mode just like you, and it works for me (on Knoppix, based on Debian). What's your Linux version?

Comment: @ott-- Ubuntu 12.10   I created a directory as git with permission drwxrwx--- and it CAN be access via gitlab, but the folder with permission of drwsrws--- CANNOT be accessed.

Comment: Are there acls active on that partitions? Check with `mount`.

Comment: @ott-- I'm pretty sure there is no ACL defined.

Comment: However, I'd like to see the mount options for all partitions. With `mount`.

Comment: @ott-- This problem has been solved! I mounted that folder(repositories) via NFS, and in NFS server, both git and gitlab users are non-existed. I added them and set proper groups for them, and everything goes well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved! I mounted that folder(repositories) via NFS, and in NFS server, both git and gitlab users are non-existed. I added them and set proper groups for them, and everything goes well!
I did some tests about this -- only when both server and client are set proper user/group, the permissions works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that /home/git have 700 permission. Adding execute permission for group (g+x) to /home/git allows you to get access:

```
# chmod g+x /home/git
```

Comment: I'm sorry but 'repositories' is the folder I cannot access to. And it DO has execute permission for group 'git', you can see this from the output of 'ls' command.

Comment: I mean x permission for /home/git folder also. Please provide the 'ls -ld /home/git' output.

Comment: I have already attached that in my original post :-)